# Boolean Algebra Consensus

Tags: boolean, logic

I have been trying to solve the following consensus: 
A'C'D + A'BD + BCD + ABC + ACD' = A'C'D + BCD + ACD'

and I think am doing something wrong. Also is there any rule 
that says BD + BC = BCD because I tried using binary tables and both expressions do not equal. I really need to see and understand the steps of the above consensus. It has given me hard time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What notation conventions are you using?  That is, what does `A+B` and `AB` mean in your notation?

Comment: boolean notation: + (OR) and *( AND), '(NOT) and so on.

Comment: There's about a dozen different "boolean" notations, none of them are universal standards.

Comment: Also, `BD + BC = BCD` is not true, so definitely not a rule. For instance <110> is true for the left-side but not for the right-side.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: Isn't circuit design and computer architecture part of computer science?

Answer (score 0):

A'C'D + BCD = A'BD which eliminates that term
BCD + ACD' = ABC which eliminates that term

now we are only left with three terms:
A'C'D + BCD + ACD'